# ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected TIMESTAMP got CHAR

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have the below query excerpt which is part of a very large query and looks like this:

`SELECT to_timestamp(TO_CHAR(CAST(coalesce(?, '01-JAN-01 01:01:01.000000 AM') AS TIMESTAMP), 'DD-MON-YY HH24MISS')`

Now, I am trying to pass value to above ***coalesce*** function through my java code like this:

```
//query.setParameter(1, "01-JAN-01 01:01:01.000000 AM"); // It works, hardcoded
query.setParameter(1, last_run_date, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP); // gives error as in the title
results = query.getResultList();
```

I am getting last_run_date (java.sql.Timestamp) from another table which looks like this: **2023-05-08 22:18:25.112**

How can I convert last_run_date parameter to the desired format i.e ***01-JAN-01 01:01:01.000000 AM***
I need it to be done through Java code. Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: The query expects a String. Make sure you are passing a String, not a timestamp or other. If you have a timestamp, just format it as a String and then use it.

Comment: @TheImpaler I have already tried this:
```query.setParameter(1, last_run_date.toString());```
Do you suggest something else?

Comment: You need to make sure you are using the correct format Oracle expects. A simple `toString()` won't do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of formatting the timestamp in the SQL query, you could format it in your Java code before setting the parameter, like:

```java
java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSS000 a");
String formattedDate = sdf.format(last_run_date);

query.setParameter(1, formattedDate);
results = query.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

`'01-JAN-01 01:01:01.000000 AM'` is not a `TIMESTAMP` data type; it is a string literal.

`COALESCE` expects both arguments to be the same data type and you are providing a `TIMESTAMP` and a string so it raises the exception:

> ```
> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected TIMESTAMP got CHAR
> ```

Because the first argument is a `TIMESTAMP` and it expects the second argument to be the same data type and it is not.

You can just use a `TIMESTAMP` literal for the second argument:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(
         ?,
         TIMESTAMP '2001-01-01 01:01:01.000000'
       )
FROM   DUAL;
```

and continue to pass your value as a `TIMESTAMP` bind variable.

---

As for the rest of your query:

- When you `CAST` a string to a `TIMESTAMP`, Oracle will perform an implicit type conversion. You should **NEVER** rely on implicit type conversions.
- Then you use `TO_CHAR` to convert to a string and then `TO_TIMESTAMP` to convert back to a `TIMESTAMP`. If you have it as a `TIMESTAMP` already, just leave it as that data type and don't keep converting back-and-forth as the operations are at-best pointless (and at-worst, may have unintended consequences such as truncating the timestamp).

So just use `COALESCE`, and no other functions.